# ReactJS: How to handle scroll to a section on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

## Question:

***What is the best way to handle scroll behavior on a particular section on the page upon some event?***

## Code:

---

```
class ContactData extends Component {

  state = {form related state}
 
  myRef = React.createRef();
 
  executeScroll = () => this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.executeScroll();
  }
  render() {
  
    if (this.state.loading) {
      form = <Spinner />;
    }
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} className={classes.ContactData}>
        <h4>Contact Information</h4>
        {form}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default ContactData;
```

## Example:

In the following GIF, you can see when I click the CONTINUE button another component (ContactData) is rendered, and with the help of reference (refs) - I can trigger this behavior.

### Component Tree:

> Checkout (Container): The main page on which child components are being rendered
>
> > ContactData (Child Component of Checkout)

[image: doubt-gif]

---

This implementation of mine is working just fine. Now, what I want to know:

#### Is there a better way to do this, or is this it?

Comment: i myself prefer ur approach but it gets messy when the project scales and u have manipulate an scroll event in another file or component . unless u save the ref somewhere like in redux or pass it along by forwardRef .

Comment: @ZahraShahrouzi Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) package.
you just have to set id for the destination section and use the code below:

```
var Scroll   = require('react-scroll');
var scroller = Scroll.scroller;

scroller.scrollTo('myScrollToElement', {
    smooth: true,
})
```

there are also other ways to do this explained in the document.